# How to use replaceWith to replace img within several div classes and div id's

Tags: jquery, html

Right now, some replaceWith code is working, the other is not. For example, this code works:

```
$('.maincontent>h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').replaceWith('<img   src="http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/6.3/img/subheaders/oak.png" class="subheader" />');
```

Here is some html code from the website regarding this particular portion if you use Inspect Element in firefox:

```
<div class="maincontent">

    <img class="subheader" src="http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/6.3/img/subheaders/stl.png"></img>
    <div id="team_wrapper">
        <div id="team-overview-wrapper">
            <div id="team-overview-profile">
                <div id="team-overlay-container">
                    <img class="team-overlay" src="/img/m25/right/339.png"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="team-bio">
                    <div class="team-logo">
                        <div class="teamimage-left" style="background-image: url("/img/m25/left/339.png");"></div>
                    </div>
```

**Note: What you cant see is the h1 element but you can see that if you look at the Page Source instead of Inspect Element.**

The h1 portion you cant see in Inspect Element, but can see if you look at page source and it looks like this:

```
<div class="maincontent">

    <h1>Oakland Raiders</h1>
                        <div id="team_wrapper">
                        <div id="team-overview-wrapper">
                        <div id="team-overview-profile">
                                    <div id="team-overlay-container">
                                                                    <img class="team-overlay" src="/img/m25/right/22.png"> 
                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="team-bio">
                                        <div class="team-logo">
                                                                            <div class="teamimage-left" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/m25/left/22.png&quot;);"></div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                <div class="team-info">
```

What I can't get working is replacing the team-overlay image or the team logo image. I have tried the following, which does nothing.

```
$('.maincontent>h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').replaceWith('<img src="http://www.papermag.com/uploaded_images/cclinemustard-funny.png" class="team-overlay" />');
```

or

```
$('.maincontent>h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').replaceWith('<img src="http://www.papermag.com/uploaded_images/cclinemustard-funny.png" class="teamimage-left" />');
```

How can I replace the teamimage-left image and the team-overlay image using replaceWith?  Im not sure why the code at the top works, yet this one doesnt.

Comment: Where is the `h1` element? As I think, it was replaced with `img.subheader`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code, including the `h1` element... the most likely reason for failure is a bad selector (i.e. the element doesn't exist). The `replaceWith` method should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vbw910qo/

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina ive added the h1 element. you can only see that when viewing page source

Comment: if you want to replace the team-overlay image, you should be doing something like $('.team-overlay').replaceWith('<img src="http://www.papermag.com/uploaded_images/cclinemustard-funny.png" class="team-overlay" />');

Comment: @DarylYoung I thought about that but the H1 element is important. This is for a daddyleagues league site. The h1 element will be the main element that will change depending on what team page you are viewing. So I think that has to be included or it will change that team-overlay for all team pages. Here is the raiders team page: [link](http://daddyleagues.com/maddenhub/team/OAK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replaceWith method should do what you want it to do.

You mention that there's a discrepancy between the *Inspect Element* and *View Source* HTML. In all likelihood, the "original" HTML (visible through *View Source*) is modified by one of the other scripts the website is using. In other words, the H1 element may really be no longer there when your JavaScript is triggered.

---

EDIT:

The *View Source* HTML indeed includes a script neer the bottom...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7MXCCVKUtiefmxvbFpMU0R6X2xIRHpPeWFHYV9vSmw3dVJIWndyUGJWSUlpX1c3THhHRUE/all42815.js"></script>
```

...which replaces the H1 headers with the image banners:

```
$('.maincontent>h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').replaceWith('<img src="http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/6.3/img/subheaders/oak.png" class="subheader" />');
```

You should either find another way to identify the team (based on the *Inspect Element* HTML), or make sure your script is run first.

Comment: @user3556644 I think I found the conflicting JS. Updated my answer to include it.

Comment: That is actually the script I am using. I was trying to add code to it to also replace a couple of the other images I mentioned.

Comment: @user3556644 Then I think it is your script that's conflicting. :-) The thing is, your code replaces the H1 with an image. Then, when you want to use the H1 again as a reference point, it's no longer there.

Comment: @user3556644 Try replacing the H1 with a div element with the team name as class or id. Then use that class or id as a reference to add content to the div.

Comment: If I have another script run first, how can I write the replacewith to do something like reference H1 and then replace teamimage-left?  Like IF h1 contains Raiders, replace teamimage-left with test.img.  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @user3556644 You can select the element you want by using something like `$('.maincontent').has('h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').find('.teamimage-left')`. Using _has_ will keep focus on the `.maincontent` element (instead of the H1). Calling _find_ searches for elements contained within that element (transferring focus to `.teamimage-left`). Then either call a replace on that element or just change the style attribute.

Comment: I might be getting closer. I tried this, but its not working. `$('.maincontent>.has(h1:contains("Oakland Raiders")').find('.teamimage-left').replaceWith('<img src="http://daddyleagues.com/img/m25/left/8.png" />');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76467/discussion-between-simon-slangen-and-user3556644).